# How to use PageBreakPalette?

Tags: packages, palettes

I would like to use `PageBreakPallete` from

http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/4094/

I did `Palettes->Install Palette..` and then in Palettes I have `PageBreakPallete`.

There show Palettes with options remove/add as but click on it doesn't make any changes.
I use Mathematica 10

Could someone help me?

Comment: Try File > Printing Settings > Show Page breaks

Comment: Yes, I can show page breaks and use option insert but what with remove? I can't find it